# give an example of a map that is conjugate but not quasi-conjugate.

Tags: functional-analysis

suppose that $T:X\to X$‎ and ‎$ T_0:X_0\to X_0$‎ are two continuous maps resp. on ‎$X$ and $X_0$. If there exists a continuous map  $J:X_0\to X$ with dense range  and $T\circ J=J \circ T_0$ then we say that $T$ quasi-conjugate with $T_0 $. and if $J$ homeomorphism then we say that $T$ conjugate with $T_0 $.

Now I know that the property of surjective is retained in the conjugate but not in the quasi-conjugate. I need an example about this sentence and give an example that is conjugate but not is quasi-conjugate.

Comment: What are your requirements on $T,T_0,X,X_0$? In general topological spaces it's rather simple to construct a counterexample. For example if $X_0$ is a discrete space and $X$ is equipped with the chaotic topology, then every constant function $J\colon X_0\to X$ will be continuous with dense image. Say $J$ takes only the value $x\in X$, then quasi-conjugateness just means that $T(x) = x$, which leaves plenty of room to have one of the maps be surjective and the other one not (notice that we really dont care about what $T_0$ is doing in this case).

Comment: $T$ and $T_0$ are linear continuous map on topological vector space. Sorry but i can't understood what you said

Comment: The fact that $T$ and $T_0$ are supposed to be linear was not included in the original question, neither that $X$ and $X_0$ are topological vector spaces. Hence why I asked (and gave obvious counterexample if they were only assumed to be topological spaces with continuous maps between them).